# grep command to extract certain word only

Tags: grep

I have a big report with many IP address shown in random lines.  All the IP address start out with 192.168.  I would like to extract only the Ip addresses and get a report that looks like:

> 192.anything.anything.anything
>
> 192.xx.xx.xx
>
> 192.xx.xx.xx

And nothing else.  I tried `cat filename | grep -w 192`
that seems to get the whole line.  I only want the full IP address.  I appreciate any information you can share with me.

Comment: Now the addresses start with 168 or 192? Or 192.168? Also there is another `cat` abuse. Just `grep pattern filename`.

Comment: All the addresses start with 192.168

Comment: @tester787: You've made a mistake in your question.  Don't use comments to say what you meant; [edit] the question and fix it.

Comment: Are all of the IP addresses followed by a space? Also, read [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html), especially example #3.

Answer (score 14):

I do this with `egrep -o` or `grep -E -o`

The -E flag in grep activates regex (which is what egrep does by default), and the -o flag prints *only* the matching string.

```
grep -E -o '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' /path/to/log
192.168.1.11
```

Answer (score 3):

```
grep -o '192.168.[0-9.]*' datfile | sort -u
```

May not be portable to ancient versions of `grep`, but `-o` seems to be in both GNU and *BSD `grep`, so... (it's also not a perfect match on a IP address, but doing the proper number ranges with regex is super annoying.)

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n 's/.*\(192.168.[^ ]*\).*/\1/p' filename
```

should do the trick.  `\>` indicates end of word.

Comment: Can you try now?

Comment: Thank you very much every one, I am good to go.   I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

As all the IP addresses start with `192.168.` you can do:

```
grep -o '192\.168\.[^ ]\+' file.txt
```

For example :

```
$ grep -o '192\.168\.[^ ]\+' bar.txt 
192.168.5.4
192.168.1.2
```